# Why doesn't this lambda calculus reducer reduce succ 0 to 1?

Tags: haskell, lambda-calculus

```
data Term = Var Integer
          | Apply Term Term
          | Lambda Term
          deriving (Eq, Show)

sub :: Term -> Integer -> Term -> Term
sub e v r = case e of
    Var x -> if x == v then r else e
    Apply m1 m2 -> Apply (sub m1 v r) (sub m2 v r)
    Lambda t -> Lambda (sub t (v + 1) r)

beta :: Term -> Term
beta t = case t of
    Apply (Lambda e) e' -> sub e 0 e'
    otherwise -> t

eta :: Term -> Term
eta t = case t of
    Lambda (Apply f (Var 0)) -> f
    otherwise -> t

reduce :: Term -> Term
reduce t = if t == t'
    then t
    else reduce t'
  where t' = beta . eta $ t
```

I tried:

```
let zero = Lambda $ Lambda $ Var 0
let succ = Lambda $ Lambda $ Lambda $ Apply (Var 1) $ (Apply (Apply (Var 2) (Var 1)) (Var 0))
reduce (Apply succ zero)
```

In GHCi, but it didn't seem to give me the expression for one (Lambda (Lambda (Apply (Var 1) (Var 0)) that I'm looking for. Instead it gives me:

```
Lambda (Lambda (Apply (Var 1) (Apply (Apply (Lambda (Lambda (Var 0))) (Var 1)) (Var 0))))
```

The variables are encoded not by name, but by how many lambdas you need to walk outwards to get the parameter.

Comment: What kind of [evaluation strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy) are looking to implement?

Comment: The simplest one to implement. Since my system is purely functional it doesn't matter.

Comment: In general, different evaluation strategies yield different normal forms even in purely functional languages.

Answer (score 3):

Your reducer, in common with the way lambda calculus is normally evaluated, doesn't reduce inside `Lambda` terms - it only removes top-level redexes. The result it produces should be *equivalent* to `one`, in that if you apply both to the same arguments you will get the same result, but not syntactically identical.

Comment: Where should this "inside reduction" take place, in the beta or eta reduction?

Comment: Inside the beta reduction is most important - you'd need to recurse on the structure of the term, either before or after trying the top level. You probably don't need the eta reduction at all.